# [ROS2] Passing additional arguments to component constructor

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I am using ROS2 Foxy on Ubuntu 20.04.
I am trying to create a node using components using [manual composition](https://docs.ros.org/en/foxy/Tutorials/Composition.html#compile-time-composition-using-ros-services-2).
I would like to pass additional arguments during the creating of the component objects. The following files were created.
###Node Code

```
#include <memory>

#include "test_pkg/test_component.hpp"
#include "rclcpp/rclcpp.hpp"

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    setvbuf(stdout, NULL, _IONBF, BUFSIZ);
    
    rclcpp::init(argc, argv);
    rclcpp::executors::MultiThreadedExecutor exec;
    rclcpp::NodeOptions options;

    RCLCPP_INFO(rclcpp::get_logger("rclcpp"), "Adding node...");
    std::string test_ID = "J1";
    auto test_node = std::make_shared(test_ID, options);
    exec.add_node(test_node);
    RCLCPP_INFO(rclcpp::get_logger("rclcpp"), "Spinning");
    exec.spin();
    rclcpp::shutdown();
    return 0;
}
```

###Component Header

```
#ifndef COMPOSITION__TEST_COMPONENT_HPP_
#define COMPOSITION__TEST_COMPONENT_HPP_

#include <test_pkg/visibility_control.h>
#include <rclcpp/rclcpp.hpp>
#include <std_msgs/msg/float32.hpp>
#include <std_srvs/srv/set_bool.hpp>

namespace test_composition
{
    class Test : public rclcpp::Node
    {
        public:
            COMPOSITION_PUBLIC
            explicit Test(const std::string &test_ID, const rclcpp::NodeOptions &options);

        protected:
            void timer_callback();
            void client_output();

        private:
            rclcpp::Publisher::SharedPtr test_publisher;
            rclcpp::TimerBase::SharedPtr test_publisher_timer;

            size_t count_;
            std::string test_name;
    };
}

#endif
```

###Component Code

```
#include "test_pkg/test_component.hpp"

#include <chrono>
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>

#include "rclcpp/rclcpp.hpp"
#include "std_msgs/msg/float32.hpp"
#include "std_srvs/srv/set_bool.hpp"

using namespace std::chrono_literals;

namespace test_composition
{
    Test::Test(const std::string &test_ID, const rclcpp::NodeOptions &options)
    : Node(test_ID, options)
    {
        RCLCPP_INFO(get_logger(), "Configuring Node...");
        test_name = test_ID;
        
        test_publisher         = create_publisher(test_name + "/speed", 0);
        test_publisher_timer   = create_wall_timer(500ms, std::bind(&Test::timer_callback, this));
    }

    void Test::timer_callback()
    {
        auto msg    = std::make_unique();
        msg->data   = ++count_;
        test_publisher->publish(std::move(msg));
    }
}

#include "rclcpp_components/register_node_macro.hpp"
RCLCPP_COMPONENTS_REGISTER_NODE(test_composition::Test)
```

I want to create multiple nodes using the Test class with different "test_ID" and therefore need to pass the additional argument to the constructor. But when I try to build the program using colcon build, I get the following error. 
###Error

```
error: no matching function for call to ‘test_composition::Test::Test(const rclcpp::NodeOptions&)’
  146 |  { ::new((void *)__p) _Up(std::forward(__args)...); }
      |    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/home//user/test_ws/src/test_pkg/src/test_component.cpp:16:5: note: candidate: ‘test_composition::Test::Test(const string&, const rclcpp::NodeOptions&)’
   16 |     Test::Test(const std::string &test_ID, const rclcpp::NodeOptions &options)
      |     ^~~~
/home/user/test_ws/src/test_pkg/src/test_component.cpp:16:5: note:   candidate expects 2 arguments, 1 provided
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/test_component.dir/build.make:63: CMakeFiles/test_component.dir/src/test_component.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:107: CMakeFiles/test_component.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:141: all] Error 2
```

Without the additional (test_id) argument the program gets build. I have also tried doing the same with a simple node without composition and it build correctly.
Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/399051/%5Bros2%5D-passing-additional-arguments-to-component-constructor/) by [Cryoschrome](https://answers.ros.org/users/102028/cryoschrome/) on ROS Answers with karma: 75 on 2022-04-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The issue is caused by your component not having the correct constructor signature required for a component. Components must have a constructor that takes rclcpp::NodeOptions as the only argument. So, simply add another constructor that calls the constructor you already have to fix this issue.

In your header file,

```
 COMPOSITION_PUBLIC
 explicit Test(const rclcpp::NodeOptions &options);
 COMPOSITION_PUBLIC
 explicit Test(const std::string &test_ID, const rclcpp::NodeOptions &options);
```

In your source file,

```
Test::Test(const rclcpp::NodeOptions &options)
: Test("", options)
{}

Test::Test(const std::string &test_ID, const rclcpp::NodeOptions &options)
: Node(test_ID, options)
{
    RCLCPP_INFO(get_logger(), "Configuring Node...");
    test_name = test_ID;

    test_publisher         = create_publisher<std_msgs::msg::float32>(test_name + "/speed", 0);
    test_publisher_timer   = create_wall_timer(500ms, std::bind(&Test::timer_callback, this));
}
```

---

Originally posted by [ijnek](https://answers.ros.org/users/73298/ijnek/) with karma: 460 on 2022-04-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1